# How to find all distinct users involved in a post identified by id?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below are 2 post objects in posts collection. I want to find all users that are involved either through answer or votes or by question itself.
The posttype determines if it is a question or an answer:

posttype =1 for Q

post type =2 for ans

```
/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : 121.0,
    "posttypeID" : 1.0,
    "tags" : [ 
        "science", 
        "technology", 
        "math"
    ],
    "viewCount" : 10.0,
    "votes" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1201.0,
            "user" : 124.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 12011.0,
            "user" : 1241.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 12012.0,
            "user" : 1241.0
        }
    ],
    "answers" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 121.0,
            "posttypeID" : 2.0,
            "tags" : [ 
                "science", 
                "technology", 
                "math"
            ],
            "viewCount" : 10.0,
            "votes" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 1201.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 1201.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 1201.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 122.0,
            "posttypeID" : 2.0,
            "tags" : [ 
                "science", 
                "technology", 
                "math"
            ],
            "viewCount" : 10.0,
            "votes" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 1201.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 1201.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 1201.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 121.0,
            "posttypeID" : 2.0,
            "tags" : [ 
                "science", 
                "technology", 
                "math"
            ],
            "viewCount" : 10.0,
            "votes" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 1201.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 1201.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 1201.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : 11.0,
    "posttypeID" : 1.0,
    "tags" : [ 
        "social", 
        "technology", 
        "arts"
    ],
    "viewCount" : 20.0,
    "votes" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1.0,
            "user" : 122.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2.0,
            "user" : 123.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 12012.0,
            "user" : 1241.0
        }
    ],
    "answers" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 12.0,
            "posttypeID" : 2.0,
            "tags" : [ 
                "social", 
                "arts", 
                "math"
            ],
            "viewCount" : 10.0,
            "votes" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 3.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 14.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 15.0,
                    "user" : 123.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 50.0,
            "posttypeID" : 2.0,
            "tags" : [ 
                "science", 
                "usa", 
                "arts"
            ],
            "viewCount" : 50.0,
            "votes" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 1202.0,
                    "user" : 120.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 1203.0,
                    "user" : 121.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 1204.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 60.0,
            "posttypeID" : 2.0,
            "tags" : [ 
                "science", 
                "technology", 
                "math"
            ],
            "viewCount" : 5.0,
            "votes" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 1205.0,
                    "user" : 121.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 1206.0,
                    "user" : 123.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 1207.0,
                    "user" : 122.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : 115.0,
    "posttypeID" : 1.0,
    "tags" : [ 
        "social", 
        "technology", 
        "arts"
    ],
    "viewCount" : 5.0,
    "votes" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1208.0,
            "user" : 122.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1209.0,
            "user" : 120.0
        }
    ],
    "answers" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 21.0,
            "posttypeID" : 2.0,
            "tags" : [ 
                "social", 
                "arts", 
                "usa"
            ],
            "viewCount" : 2.0,
            "votes" : {}
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 110.0,
            "posttypeID" : 2.0,
            "tags" : [ 
                "wiki", 
                "usa", 
                "arts"
            ],
            "viewCount" : 0.0,
            "votes" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 1210.0,
                    "user" : 124.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 100.0,
            "posttypeID" : 2.0,
            "tags" : [ 
                "usa", 
                "wiki"
            ],
            "viewCount" : 5.0,
            "votes" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 1211.0,
                    "user" : 125.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is users collection

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 124.0,
    "CreationDate" : "2013-05-08T18:26:05.680",
    "DisplayName" : "hairboat",
    "age" : 23.0,
    "UpVote" : 1.0,
    "DownVote" : 0.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 1241.0,
    "CreationDate" : "2013-05-08T18:26:05.680",
    "DisplayName" : "jamie",
    "age" : 40.0,
    "UpVote" : 10.0,
    "DownVote" : 5.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 120.0,
    "CreationDate" : "2013-05-08T18:26:05.680",
    "DisplayName" : "jamie",
    "age" : 40.0,
    "UpVote" : 10.0,
    "DownVote" : 5.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 121.0,
    "CreationDate" : "2013-05-08T19:01:56.490",
    "DisplayName" : "Casey",
    "age" : 30.0,
    "UpVote" : 120.0,
    "DownVote" : 10.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : 122.0,
    "CreationDate" : "2013-05-08T19:03:27.963",
    "DisplayName" : "user15",
    "age" : 30.0,
    "UpVote" : 1.0,
    "DownVote" : 0.0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : 123.0,
    "CreationDate" : "2013-05-08T19:03:27.963",
    "DisplayName" : "user15",
    "age" : 30.0,
    "UpVote" : 1.0,
    "DownVote" : 0.0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : 12.0,
    "CreationDate" : "2013-05-08T19:03:27.963",
    "DisplayName" : "user15",
    "age" : 30.0,
    "UpVote" : 1.0,
    "DownVote" : 0.0
}

Comment: By _question itself_, meaning that the post should have a `user` too? It is missing in your document.

Comment: yes, I have added